# How to scale a polygon without translating the polygon given a list of coordinates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, geometry, polygon, konvajs

I have an array of coordinates `[x1,y1, x2, y2 ....]` which represents a polygon on a html canvas. I am drawing the polygon using KonvaJS. I am trying to retrieve the scaled coordinates for the polygon where `[x1, y1, x2, y2 ...]` is the scaled coordinates.

I have tried the following:

1. Using JSTS https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts to add buffer to the coordinates.
   Followed this snippet http://jsfiddle.net/qdv1n4yL/7/ and tried in integrate into my react/typescript app and created the snippet as shown below
   function vectorCoordinates2JTS (polygon) {
   var coordinates: any = [];

   ```
   for (var i = 0; i < polygon.length; i++) {
       coordinates.push(new Coordinate(polygon[i].x, polygon[i].y));
   }
   return coordinates;
   }

   function inflatePolygon(poly, spacing) {
       var geoInput = vectorCoordinates2JTS(poly);
       geoInput.push(geoInput[0]);

       var geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

       var shell = geometryFactory.createPolygon(geoInput);
       var polygon = new BufferOp(poly);
       console.log(polygon.getResultGeometry())

       var inflatedCoordinates: any = [];
       var oCoordinates;
       oCoordinates = polygon.shell.points.coordinates;
       console.log(oCoordinates.length)
       for (let i = 0; i < oCoordinates.length; i++) {
           var oItem;
           oItem = oCoordinates[i];
           inflatedCoordinates.push(Math.ceil(oItem.x), Math.ceil(oItem.y));
       }
       return inflatedCoordinates;
   }
   ```

Here I am passing `poly` as `[{x: 1, y:1}, {x:2, y:2}]` and spacing as 1.5. It breaks on this line here `polygon.getResultGeometry()` with an error.

2. Also tried using this library to get the transformed coordinates http://turfjs.org/docs/#transformScale but it returns me a bunch of coordinates which i cant seem to use and get my end result as just a simple list of scaled coordinates.

My overall requirements for solving this problem is the polygon should have a cushioning like buffer around the original polygon which can be used to detect collision. I was able to get the collision detection between the polygon and a point working but been stuck on adding the scale/buffer for the past few days. Any help or follow up questions to this problem is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need mouse or touch events, for point hit detection, so to extend the edge of the polygon so that you get a larger area for collision detection, Konva has the hitStrokeWidth parameter. See point 2 on [this docs page](https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Custom_Hit_Region.html).

The gist is that Konva provides its own hit detection feature by drawing the shape in an off-screen canvas but inflating the stroke width. For example:

```
  const line = new Konva.Line({
    x: 50,
    y: 100,
    points: [0, 0, 50, 0, 50, 100, 0, 100],
    tension: 1,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    hitStrokeWidth: 20,
    stroke: 'black',
  });
  layer.add(line);
```

What this does is to draw the stroke with the given hitStrokeWidth size - in this case 20px. But only on the hit detection canvas offscreen. You can then avoid the need for the calculation you are attempting.